# select specific lines with the data.table package

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following (simplified) dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("A","A","B","B","B"),x=c(1,2,3,3,4))
df
  a x
1 A 1
2 A 2
3 B 3
4 B 3
5 B 4
```

Since I'm working with large datasets, I use the data.table package.

Is there a way to get those lines in df, where x is minimal grouped by a. So in this case, I want to select lines 1,3 and 4.

Something like

```
df[,min(x),by=a]
```

But that doesn't give me the lines I wanna have, it just Shows me the minmum values for x grouped by a.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a=c("A","A","B","B","B"), x=c(1,2,3,3,4))
```

**These give only unique rows:**

```
dt[, .SD[which.min(x)], by=a]
```

Or alternatively:

```
setkeyv(dt, c("a","x"))
dt[unique(dt[,a]), mult="first"]
```

**Since you want to have all ties:**

```
dt[,.SD[x==min(x)], by=a]
```

You could also use:

```
setkeyv(dt,c("a","x"))
dt[dt[unique(dt[,a]), mult="first"]]
```

Which could be more efficient if you have very big groups.

Comment: He also wants line 4!

Comment: Thanks. I added a solution for that.

Comment: thanks, this is nice. But as you said, it's probably not the most efficient way, maybe it's possible to get rid of the "=="?

Comment: See the last solution. What is most efficient depends on the number and size of groups.

Comment: Well, create representative dummy data, so we can test solutions.

Comment: I will, but let me first try your second solution

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
R) dt <- data.table(a=c("A","A","B","B","B"),x=c(1,2,3,3,4))
R) dt[dt[,list(IDX=.I[x==min(x)]),by=a]$IDX]
   a x
1: A 1
2: B 3
3: B 3
```

That should be quicker if you want ties (as I understood you wanted)